# DC - Generative Adverserial Network. Issues in understanding code

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

This a part of the code for a Deconvolutional-Convoltional Generative Adversarial Network (DC-GAN)

```
discriminator.trainable = False
ganInput = Input(shape=(100,))
# getting the output of the generator
# and then feeding it to the discriminator
# new model = D(G(input))
x = generator(ganInput)
ganOutput = discriminator(x)
gan = Model(input=ganInput, output=ganOutput)
gan.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam())
```

I do not understand what the line `ganInput = Input(shape=(100,))` does.
Clearly `ganInput` is a variable but what is `Input`? Is it a function ?
If `Input` is a function then what will `ganInput` contain ?

Then it is `ganInput` is fed into the generator since it is an empty variable (assuming) it will not matter. Next `ganOutput` catches the output of the `discriminator`.

Then comes the problem. I read about the `Model` API but I do not understand fully what it does.

To summarise these are my problems : What is the role of `ganInput` and what is `Input` in the second line. And what is `Model` doing and what is it?

Using Keras with TensorFlow backend
COMPLETE SOURCE CODE : https://github.com/yashk2810/DCGAN-Keras/blob/master/DCGAN.ipynb

Please ask for any more clarification / details required. If you know the answer to even one of my queries I will request you to please answer it will be a huge help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What is input: Notice the wildcard import of `keras.layers`. In context, `Input` is `keras.layers.Input`. Generally, if you see a function or class that wasn't defined or explicitly imported in Python, it got there via a wildcard import, i.e.

```
from keras.layers import *
```

That means import everything from `keras.layers` directly into the workspace.

What is `model`: The `model` object is essentially the interface for making neural networks with Keras.

You can read about `model` and `keras.layers.Input` at the [model docs](https://keras.io/models/model/) or at this [model guide](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/) since I'm not very familiar with Keras.

What's going on in the example is they define generator and discriminator as `Sequential`s. But the GAN model is a little more complex than a standard old `Sequential`. The authors deal with that by marking the data that needs fed in at every iteration (in this case, just the random noise for the generator - `ganInput`) as a `keras.layers.Input`. Then, like you said, `ganOutput` catches the output of the discriminator. Since we have two distinct `Sequential`s that need wrapped together, the authors use the `model` API.